# How to get columns data which are having different values after comparing with other table?

Tags: sql-server

I have two Tables say `Table-A` and `Table-B` having same table structure (means number of columns are same) and having same number of Records with same Primary key value.

It is having `Column-Id` data is same in both the tables but some columns values are Different.

Now I want a  **Select**  query which will return those columns only which are having different data in `Tables-A` and `Table-B`

Example :

```
Table-A
ID  Name   RollNo  Status
1   Gourav 22      1

Table-B
ID  Name   RollNo  Status
1   Gourav 24      0
```

OUTPUT Required is :

```
Table-C
Id  RollNo-A  RollNo-B  sts-A  sts-B
1   22        24        1      0
```

Please suggest.
Please provide Solution in Sql 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

```
SELECT      A.Id
        ,   A.RollNo AS [RollNo_A]
        ,   B.RollNo AS [RollNo_B]
        ,   A.Status AS [Status_A]
        ,   B.Status AS [Status_B]
FROM        dbo.TableA  A
INNER JOIN  dbo.TableB  B
ON          A.Id        =  B.Id
WHERE       A.RollNo    <> B.RollNo
OR          A.Status    <> B.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just do a inner join if you are sure both all IDs must be present in
>   both the tables. If not use left outer join with the left table being
>   the parent table. Try this:

select a.id, a.rollno [rollno-A], b.rollno [rollno-B], a.status as [sts-A], 
b.status as [sts-B]
from @tableA A
INNER JOIN
@tableB B
ON a.id = B.id